# Java: empty char without space

Tags: java, null, char, ternary-operator

I am making a program that puts a zero before a day or month if its < 10.
I work with the ternary operator and it works well if my dates are < 10.

11-02-1999 is good

But if its higher than zero it gives

11- 12-1999

I dont want that whitespace. How do i remove it.
This is my code

```
nuldag = (dag < 10 ? '0' : '\0');
nulmonth = (month < 10 ? '0' : '\0');
System.out.println("Date is:  " +nulday+day+"-"+nulmonth+month+"-"+year);
```

Comment: You have `nuldag` and `dag`, but you mean `nulday` and `day`.

Comment: I'm Dutch, just a wrong translation.

Comment: You used `nulday` later though, so you need to rename them to be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this with a char. Use a String instead:

```
 String nuldag = (dag < 10 ? "0" : "");
 String nulmonth = (month < 10 ? "0" : "");
 System.out.println("Date is:  " + nuldag + day  + "-" + nulmonth + month + "-" + year);
```

**EDIT:**
I add the suggestion of Peter Lawrey that such formatting tasks are better solved using String formatting, e.g.

```
System.out.printf("Date is %2d-%2d-%d%n", day, month, year);
```

Comment: This is the answer to the question but I would add that a better solution would be to use a format `System.out.printf("Date is %2d-%2d-%d%n", day, month, year);` +1